# setting element to opacity: 0 disables it in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, opacity

I am trying to mask an upload input element by my usual method of setting its opacity to 0, and then overlaying it with an image (with pointer-events set to none) so that it effectively masks the input with a nicer-looking button, but when you click that area, the submit still fires.

This is all fine and happy except in Firefox, where it seems setting opacity: 0 on an element disables it?

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Could you use two elements one on the top of the other?

Comment: What Firefox version are you testing in?  I just tried in Firefox 19 and setting opacity:0 doesn't change anything about click event handling....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `@-moz-document url-prefix() {` for excluding firefox css. example like this

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .content {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: sass wont validate this unfortunately

Comment: moved it to a css file to target this element only and it works to deal with the element in firefox only - thanks!

Comment: Note that this is likely to stop working when the prefix is dropped from `@-moz-document`, so it's worth figuring out what's actually going on here.  Do you have a testcase showing the problem?